# drools validation unique and dependent

Tags: java, collections, drools

I have a collection of `POJOs` in memory and these `POJOs` come from other system. I have the following two problems with them:

1. I want to know what POJO is duplicate in terms of properties value.
2. I also validate against other collection i.e I have 200 shops in a city and shop ids start from 1 and ends at 200. I got a data from the shop and it submits me 500 as shop id. I want to verify the data is correct according to my collection of data or not?

I am currently stuck and don't know how to perform these operation.
I am collecting data for the market trends, shops from all over the city are registered with us. We assigned ID to each of the store. Store keeper will send us their selling details in the plain file format. My task is to collect correct data in DB. If shop or goods id doesn't match with my collection, then that record would be incorrect and I notify the shop keeper that this record is invalid. If file contains same row two or more times then also, I notify that it is duplicate.

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us what you've tried, or at least describe the specs in enough detail for a real solution to be offered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have `equals()` method implemented for these `POJOs` to say that an object is duplicate of another one. Then, you can keep inserting the `POJOs` you received, into a `java.util.Set` and everytime you receive a new one, you can check if the POJO is already received, using `set.contains()`.

For #2, you can maintain a `Map` of ID to the object in that other collection to check if a newly arrived `POJO` is a valid one present in that map.

AFAIK, `drools` requires you to provide a canonical representation of your object to run the rules on the state of the object. The above two validations require you to maintain those data structures irrespective of using drools or any other rule engine.